# SlideUp() function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

After using `animate()` to exact height for div, closing div with `slideUp()` function. But there is one problem: `slideUp()` leaves inline height (that created `animate()` function on the fly) as is. It doesn't remove it after function execution.  Is there any other way to do it?

For opening

```
$(minreg_link).click(function () {
    if(ftr_form_cntr.is(':visible')){  
        if(minreg_div.is(':visible')){
            return
        }
        ftr_form_cntr.find("div").fadeOut();
        ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).animate({
            height:"100"
        },1000);
        minreg_div.fadeIn(1000);
        return;
    }
    ftr_form_cntr.show().stop(true, true).animate({
        height:"100"
    },1000);
    minreg_div.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

for closing

```
$(closer_link).click(function () {
    ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).slideUp(1000).find("div").fadeOut(1000);
    $(closer_div).hide(1000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ftr_form_cntr.stop(true, true).slideUp(1000, function(){
  ftr_form_cntr.height(0);
}).find("div").fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu hi friend, does my solution solve your problem??